# Continuous bounded martingale of finite variation (ito lemma?)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

**The question:**

Suppose that $(M_t) $ $ : t \in [0,\infty)$
is a bounded continuous martingale with finite variation. Prove that
$M_t^2
 = M_0^2
 + 2 \int_0^t 
M_s dM_s,$
where the final integral is almost surely well-defined. (Hint: Cite here known results about
one-dimensional functions of bounded variation.) Deduce that $M$ is almost surely constant

**My attempt**

Im fairly sure the last part is quite easy by taking the expected value of both sides and knowing that the stochastic integral is a martingale.

My struggle lies within the first bit. Can I just use Itô formula using $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} $?

That is to say: $f(M_t) -f(M_0) = \int_0^t f'(M_s)dM_s + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^tf''(M_s)ds$

This then gives me $\frac{M_t^2}{2} - \frac{M_0^2}{2} = \int_0^tM_sdM_s + t$

This is very nearly what I need but I have the annoying $+t$ on the end. Can I get rid of this somehow? I haven't at all used the continuity, boundedness or finite variation so i think I've done something wrong. What is the "well known result" the hint suggests I use?

**EDIT**

My textbook states:[image]

I do not understand how any of the equalities follow or hold? Is it that because the process is of finite variation we can just. use normal calculus? What is the formula being used here please

Comment: Because $M_t$ is finite variation process, you can show that $d\langle M, M\rangle_t=0$. So when you apply Ito's lemma,  the term $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f''(M_t)d\langle M, M\rangle_t=0$. 
Typically Ito's lemma is first proved for Brownian motion (which is not a finite variation process) and in that case you get $d\langle B, B\rangle_t=dt$.

Comment: Brilliant. I had been using itos formula incorrrectly! thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because the process is of finite variation, we can just use normal calculus.  Specifically, using integration by parts we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t M_s dM_s = M_t^2 - M_0^2 - \int_0^t M_s dM_s
\end{align*}
and the claim follows by simply rearranging that expression.